# How do I assign an array to an HTML form input value?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I would like to assign a value of an array to an HTML input element.

In my browser console, the following code works:

```
let between0400am0800am = [1669352400000, 1669438800000];
document.getElementById("time400am800amEveryDay").value = between0400am0800am;
```

However, in my code, the same code doesn't seem to work.

Find below my html code:

```
<div class="form-check">
   <input class="form-check-input checkbox" type="checkbox" id="time400am800amEveryDay">
</div>
```

Naturally, the desired outcome is:

```
<div class="form-check">
   <input class="form-check-input checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1669352400000,1669438800000" id="time400am800amEveryDay">
</div>
```

Comment: So use toString() or join() to convert the array to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `Array.prototype.join()` function. You can pass an parameter which will inserted between the array items.

```js
let between0400am0800am = [1669352400000, 1669438800000];
document.getElementById("time400am800amEveryDay").value = between0400am0800am.join(",");
```